# Preferred way to sum different time series together (in software)

Tags: time-series, algorithms, data-imputation, binning, aggregation

Is there a canonical/best approach to computationally summing different time series together?

What I mean by that is the operation

$$
\sum_i{s_i(t)} = S(t)
$$

where $s_i(t)$ is the $i$-th time series, and $S(t)$ is a resulting time series.

In practice, a time series will be represented in software as something like an array of tuples `[(t1,v1), ..., (tn,vn)]` where the `t`'s are some kind of (date)timestamps and the `v`'s are the values that the series happens to have at the particular times `t`'s.

The practical problem comes from the fact that usually we will have real time series which do not have exactly matching timestamps (especially if the timestamps are high-precision and contain time and not just dates), or some series may be missing some values at some timestamps that the others instead have.

For example, I might have $n$ streams of data that contain the count of some HTTP requests of different instances of my application. I would like to have the "sum time series" out of all of them, i.e. a time series that shows the total amount of HTTP requests across all instances, over time.

Or I might have a continuous metric instead of a discrete one, like prices, or memory usage, or any other thing that might make sense to sum across different similar series.

What could be the best approach (soundest, from a mathematical point of view, and most efficient, from an algorithmic point of view) to achieve this?

Are there renowned scientific libraries or pieces of data-manipulation software that implement operations like this one, and if so, what do they do?

To give an example of something that one might try and of its shortcomings:

A simple approach might be to round all timestamps to a high enough granularity so to have some big overlap among the series (for example, I round timestamps to the second, and I consider something like a data point that happened at 00:00:01.23456 to have happened at 00:00:01). This effectively is equivalent to perform binning with a small bin's width (1 second, in my example).

There remain a couple of big "degrees of freedom" to lock before being able to actually sum the series now: 1) what do we do if multiple data points fall into the same bin? We need to aggregate their values into one somehow, and which aggregation to use might depend on our use case. It might be correct to sum their values, or it might be correct to take their average, etc. 2) how do we handle missing data? It might still be that, after binning, we got bins (timestamps) with no data (no value) inside, for some of the series. What should the resulting series have at that timestamp? No value? Or do we assign some default value to the series which have missing points? Also here, it seems that it might depend on the specific use case.

Answer (score 2):

The "best" solution is going to be domain dependent. Most proposed solutions to deal with mixed frequencies or different timestamps fall into some flavor of the two categories below.

1. Binning and aggregations (what you've already suggested) --> Information loss
2. Oversampling/imputation --> Increased bias and memory requirements

Oversampling would do something like grab the timestamps of the highest frequency time series and use them for synchronization or make a new clock that has a higher sampling rate than all series you are summing.

To synchronize all timeseries before performing a mathematical operation you would set timestamps for all series to be equal based on the clock from above and perform some imputation for timestamps where you do not have data. Literature exists for more advanced imputation methods, but imputation may be as simple as using the last observed value or a linear interpolation between the last and next observed value.

At this point all your series should have the same timestamps and performing any operations on them should be straight forward.

I'm aware of the following R library and function that implements a method that falls into the binning category where the bins are essentially variable and aggregation chooses the most recent observation in a bin: https://rdrr.io/rforge/highfrequency/man/refreshTime.html

Answer (score 1):

You should first satisfy yourself that the intended sum makes sense: only values measured in like units can be added.

Next you should ask yourself whether the series you try to add are "stocks" or "flows", to use the common econometric jargon. A stock is a variable which has a meaningful instantaneous value (e.g. voltage, interest rate) while a flow is a variable whose instantaneous value is meaningless and can only be interpreted as an aggregated variable over a period of time: electric charge flowing through a cable, GDP of a country.

If your series are of the stock variety, adding series with different timestamps will likely have no meaning whatsoever. If your series are of the flow variety and the values you have, even if dated differently, represent aggregates for the same period of time, you might be able to add them.

Comment: It is not very clear why the time series functions for stock variables can not be meaningfully added. For instance, if I have time series for the queue lengths at different cash registers in a store, then I could add these together to get the total queue length in the entire store.

Comment: Also, isn't this post more like a comment about the question rather than giving an answer to the question. "You should first..." , this leaves open what we need to do second.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, I understood the question as adding time series with different time stamps. Your example of queue lengths at different cash registers adding up to total queue length makes sense if you consider observations at the same time. Adding up queue lengths of the different cash registers at different times would probably have no useful interpretation.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, you may be rigth in that this is more of a comment than an answer. I thought that may be after consideration of the issue, no answer (nor question) might be needed.

Comment: But say that we have data for different cash registers with different time stamps. What are we to do with them? Your answer is like arguing that we cannot do anything because we are dealing with 'stocks'. That argument seems wrong. The problem is the different timestamps and not that the data are 'stocks'. The problem of different timestamps may be overcome. For instance we could use estimates of the time series for different points in time.

Comment: Also, flow variables have the same problems. If I have one time series with amount per week and another with amount per month, then they do not represent the same periods of time and adding is difficult.

Comment: The problem is different timestamps when series are stocks (the two things coupled). If series are flows over non-ovelapping intervals, they can be added (assuming same units, etc.)  The problem of temporal aggregation  when time intervals are of different length (weeks, months) is an entirely different one.

Comment: The question doesn't state that the variables are stocks. It could just as well be flow variables which have gaps in the data or different times of measurement. For instance it could be measurements of temperature (a stock variable) and wind speed (a flow variable) at weather stations. The treatment for these two will not be different because the one is a flow variable and the other is a stock variable.

Comment: Speed is an instantaneous magnitude, a stock. The question did not give details, that's why I thought it was worthwhile to make explicit the distinction, since different treatments are required for flows and stocks. The system is warning me not to engage into extended discussion in comments, hence I think I should stop here.

Comment: Speed is a flow variable, but it can be expressed for an infinitesimal small time period.

Answer (score 0):

As Ted mentioned, binning/aggregation and oversampling/imputation are usually performed.

You could also try interpolation between timestamps for the sparser series. You could build a local model between the n points in the sparer series and sample from the interpolated region.

If your goal is to use the resultant time series for modeling, and the sampling mismatch is quite small, you could try modeling with lstms/transformers. These complex models would be able to perform well even if there is a small timestamp mismatch or a small amount of missing samples.